# django template custom filter

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm fairly new to django and I believe this is django template related question. I've got a project template where there is a certain value, namely {{ tenant_name }} which tells the tenant name. I've used for loop to find out all tenant names which works fine.

How ever, all of the tenants have units under them and when I try to display units per tenant with for loop it loops all units to all tenants which is not what I want to do. note: self.tenant can't be used in this case as the user doesn't have a tenant yet.

I've tried to solve this using custom filter, by registering it and loading it to the template and then filtering like so: {{ tenant_name|filter_units }}, however this doesn't seem to work for some reason. My question is this: is it possible to extract tenant_name from the template to the filter, use that value in the filter to search for units and return it back to the template? If so, could you possibly show me how? If it is not possible, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: some code that I've tried so far:

filter: (Note: get_accepted_list is imported function to find units and it works)

```
from tenant.api import get_accepted_list
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='filter_units')
def find_tenant_units(request):
    tenant = getattr(request, 'tenant_name', None)
    return get_accepted_list(tenant_name=tenant).order_by('tenant_name', 'id')
```

Part of the template:

```py
{% load filter_units %}

    {% for unit in units %}
    {{ unit.tenant_name|filter_units }}


    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I would like to help you but can't follow your problem without you providing some code and examples. Please update your question and / or see "how to ask": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the tenant? What do you mean with units? What is the result you get without a filter and what result do you want to archive? What does the model look like? I know its easy for you to understand your code, but we dont have any idea what is going on here :)

Comment: Tenant is a model which represents one company. There are many companies under tenant model. Units are tenants units, meaning they are for example store locations. One tenant(company) can have multiple stores, offices etc. Without the filter that I've tried to make it shows multiple company names as in {{tenant_name}}. What I want to achieve is to show the units that these companies have by using their name to search for their units in the filter. So, I would extract tenant_name from template, use the name with my get_accepted_list() function and return the units of that certain company.